# Thread timing in visual basic

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I am using a http request to check for an account status from a local web server, I have added a small delay to the PHP to mimic the behavior of a remote server.

I'm trying to enable a spinner while the WebRequest is in progress, I know all the functionality of the code works, but my problem is the spinner (spinthread) doesn't show until the WebRequest (reqthread) is complete.

```
Dim spinthread As System.Threading.Thread
Dim reqthread As System.Threading.Thread
Private Delegate Sub spinDelegate()
Private Delegate Sub reqDelegate()

Private Sub spintog() 'spinnner toggle
    If Me.InvokeRequired Then
        Me.Invoke(New spinDelegate(AddressOf spintog))
    Else
        If MetroProgressSpinner1.Visible = True Then
            MetroProgressSpinner1.Visible = False

        Else

            MetroProgressSpinner1.Visible = True

        End If
    End If
End Sub


Private Sub reqsub()
    If Me.InvokeRequired Then
        Me.Invoke(New reqDelegate(AddressOf reqsub))
    Else

        ' Create a request using a URL that can receive a post. 
        Dim request As WebRequest = WebRequest.Create("http://localhost/json/login.php ")
        ' Set the Method property of the request to POST.
        request.Method = "POST"
        ' Create POST data and convert it to a byte array.
        Dim postData As String = "username=" & username.Text & "&password=" & password.Text
        Dim byteArray As Byte() = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData)
        ' Set the ContentType property of the WebRequest.
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        ' Set the ContentLength property of the WebRequest.
        request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length
        ' Get the request stream.
        Dim dataStream As Stream = request.GetRequestStream()
        ' Write the data to the request stream.
        dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length)
        ' Close the Stream object.
        dataStream.Close()
        ' Get the response.
        Dim response As WebResponse = request.GetResponse()
        ' Display the status.
        Console.WriteLine(CType(response, HttpWebResponse).StatusDescription)
        ' Get the stream containing content returned by the server.
        dataStream = response.GetResponseStream()
        ' Open the stream using a StreamReader for easy access.
        Dim reader As New StreamReader(dataStream)
        ' Read the content.
        Dim responseFromServer As String = reader.ReadToEnd()
        ' Display the content.
        Dim loginresponse As String = responseFromServer

        debug.Text = loginresponse


        If loginresponse.Contains("fail") Then
            faillabel.Visible = True
        Else
            faillabel.Visible = False


        End If

        ' Clean up the streams.
        reader.Close()
        dataStream.Close()
        response.Close()

    End If
End Sub

Private Sub login_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles login.Click

    spinthread = New System.Threading.Thread(AddressOf spintog)
    spinthread.Start()

    reqthread = New System.Threading.Thread(AddressOf reqsub)
    reqthread.Start()

End Sub
```

Comment: Your `reqsub` ends up running twice: once on the new thread (where it doesn't do anything except `Invoke` itself) and once on the main thread - with the second run blocking your UI, which is why you can't see the spinner for a while. Take away the `InvokeRequired/Invoke` though, and `reqsub` will run on the new (background) thread as expected, then hit `debug.Text = loginresponse` and drop out with a cross-threading exception because you can't update UI controls from a non-UI thread. That's a double-edged sword.

Comment: I'd recommend checking out some async programming tutorials for absolute beginners to get your fundamentals right and rewriting the above from the ground up. If you're targeting .NET 4.5 or above, do look at Task Parallel Library and `async/await` - it will pay off in the long term.

Comment: You can certainly use `InvokeRequired` and `Invoke` but you should be executing ONLY the UI updates on the UI thread, not that whole method.  Read this: http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?498387-Accessing-Controls-from-Worker-Threads.  That is a bit old school though.  At least look at using a `BackgroundWorker`, which is a good option for WinForms apps.